# Xamarin Media plugin doesn't works on Android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, media, nullreferenceexception

I've installed the plugin `Xam.Plugin.Media`.
The plugin works fine on IOS but on Andorid the app crash as soon it starts.

I have followed the readme.txt that come after the installation of the plugin, so my files are:

**MainActivity.cs:**

```
using System;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using Plugin.Permissions;
using Plugin.Permissions.Abstractions;
using FFImageLoading.Forms.Droid;

namespace SgatMobileV2.Droid {
    [Activity(Label = "SgatMobileV2", Icon = "@drawable/icon", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle) {
            TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
            ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);

            CachedImageRenderer.Init(enableFastRenderer: true); // Inizializza il plugin FFImageLoading

            LoadApplication(new App());
        }

        public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, global::Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults) {
            PermissionsImplementation.Current.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }
}
```

**Resources/xml/file_paths.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <external-files-path name="my_images" path="Pictures" />
  <external-files-path name="my_movies" path="Movies" />
</paths>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="it.volos.SgatMobile" android:installLocation="auto">
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="23" android:targetSdkVersion="26" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
  <application android:label="SgatMobileV2.Android" android:icon="@drawable/icon">
    <provider android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider" android:authorities="it.volos.SgatMobile.fileprovider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true">
      <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
    </provider>
  </application>
</manifest>
```

But after the app starts, this error is triggered:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Can anyone help me please?

Thank you!

Comment: What version of Xamarin.Forms/plugin are you using?

Comment: @hichame.yessou I'm using the Xamarin.Forms 2.5.0.122203 version and the plugin 3.1.3 version.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like that after `cleaning the solution`, `closing Visual Studio`, and `deleting the obj and bin folders` my project works fine again....

And I set also the build action of my **file_paths.xml** to `AndroidResource`.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

According to plugin's [documentation](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin), you should add this line in OnCreate() method:

```
Plugin.CurrentActivity.CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity = this;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and inheriting MainActivitiy class from `global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsApplicationActivity` rather than    `global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity` solved my problem.

Do not forget to follow instructions on ReadMe file. e.g creating MainApplication.cs file.

```
[Application]
public class MainApplication : Application, Application.IActivityLifecycleCallbacks {
    public MainApplication(IntPtr handle, JniHandleOwnership transer) : base(handle, transer) {
    }

    public override void OnCreate() {
        base.OnCreate();
        RegisterActivityLifecycleCallbacks(this);
        //A great place to initialize Xamarin.Insights and Dependency Services!
    }

    public override void OnTerminate() {
        base.OnTerminate();
        UnregisterActivityLifecycleCallbacks(this);
    }

    public void OnActivityCreated(Activity activity, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity = activity;
    }

    public void OnActivityDestroyed(Activity activity) {
    }

    public void OnActivityPaused(Activity activity) {
    }

    public void OnActivityResumed(Activity activity) {
        CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity = activity;
    }

    public void OnActivitySaveInstanceState(Activity activity, Bundle outState) {
    }

    public void OnActivityStarted(Activity activity) {
        CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity = activity;
    }

    public void OnActivityStopped(Activity activity) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I kept getting System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object, even after completing all the steps

I was able to fix my problem based on the solution provided above by rather inheriting from global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsApplicationActivity instead of global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity

Example of code change:
from

```
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
```

to

```
public class MainActivity :  global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsApplicationActivity
```